# java juint testing which delta to chose to avoid floatting point error

Tags: java, junit, floating-point, assert, delta

I am using jUnit to test my Java app (I am totally new to Java).

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double A = 50000.0;
        double B = 1.1;
         System.out.println("Result" + A * B);
    }
}
```

A 'normal' answer (from a mathematical perspective) is : 55000

However java returns:

```
Result 55000.00000000001
```

Thus, my test fails because the assertconsiditon is not respected

My jUnit test looks like:

```
        Assert.assertEquals("55000", <javaResult>, 0.0);
```

I belive the problem is due to the last parameter called delta. Because when I try to change the delta randomly. The following does not give a failure (i.e. the test passed as expected)

```
        Assert.assertEquals("55000", <javaResult>, 0.01);
```

So my question is : assuming I have to perform exclusively multiplications, which delta should I chose? (I do not feel confortable to randomly chose 0.01 just because it works...)

Comment: By “perform exclusively multiplications,” do you mean you will always be comparing a decimal result to the result of exactly one multiplication of two numbers? If so, a good error bound can be calculated, but it will be relative to the size of the numbers, not absolute, so there is no single constant you can use for the tolerance.

Comment: Hello Eric yes you understood it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the normal range (magnitudes in [2<sup>−1022</sup>, 2<sup>1024</sup>)), a Java `double` has a 53-bit significand, so the step size between adjacent representable values is at most one part in 2<sup>52</sup>. Whenever a number is converted to the `double` format using round-to-nearest, the result, if it is in the normal range, is at most half a step away from the original number.

Thus, if *a* is the value of a decimal numeral that is converted to a `double` value `a`, then `a` = *a*•(1+*e*), where |*e*| ≤ 2<sup>−53</sup>.

Consider comparing the mathematical product of two numbers, *xy*, to the result of converting the two numbers to `double` `x` and `y` and multiplying them to produce a `double` result. We might write the exact product *xy* as a decimal numeral, but, in passing it to `assertEquals`, it will be converted to `double`, so we actually pass *xy*•(1+*e*<sub>0</sub>) for some *e*<sub>0</sub> as described above.

Similarly, *x* is converted to some `x` equal to *x*•(1+*e*<sub>1</sub>), and *y* is converted to some `y` equal to *y*•(1+*e*<sub>2</sub>). Then we multiply these to form (*x*•(1+*e*<sub>1</sub>))•(*y*•(1+*e*<sub>2</sub>))•(1+*e*<sub>3</sub>).

Finally, we compare *xy*•(1+*e*<sub>0</sub>) to (*x*•(1+*e*<sub>1</sub>))•(*y*•(1+*e*<sub>2</sub>))•(1+*e*<sub>3</sub>). How different can they be?

The latter is *xy*•(1+*e*<sub>1</sub>)•(1+*e*<sub>2</sub>)•(1+*e*<sub>3</sub>), so the difference is xy•((1+*e*<sub>1</sub>)•(1+*e*<sub>2</sub>)•(1+*e*<sub>3</sub>)−(1+*e*<sub>0</sub>)) = *xy*•(*e*<sub>1</sub>+*e*<sub>2</sub>+*e*<sub>3</sub>+*e*<sub>1</sub>*e*<sub>2</sub>+*e*<sub>2</sub>*e*<sub>3</sub>+*e*<sub>1</sub>*e*<sub>3</sub>+*e*<sub>1</sub>*e*<sub>2</sub>*e*<sub>3</sub>
−*e*<sub>0</sub>). We can easily see the error term has its greatest magnitude when *e*<sub>0</sub> is −2<sup>−53</sup> and the other errors are +2<sup>−53</sup>. Then it is 4•2<sup>−53</sup> + 3•2<sup>−106</sup> + 2<sup>−159</sup>. Whether *x* or *y* is positive or negative, the greatest magnitude of this error bound remains the same, so we may characterize this bound on the difference as |*xy*|•(4•2<sup>−53</sup> + 3•2<sup>−106</sup> + 2<sup>−159</sup>).

We cannot compute this exactly using `double`, for three reasons:

- *xy* may not be exactly representable.
- 4•2<sup>−53</sup> + 3•2<sup>−106</sup> + 2<sup>−159</sup> is not representable.
- When these two values are multiplied using `double`, there may be another rounding error.

To deal with the first problem, suppose we have absolute value of the desired product, *xy*, as a decimal numeral `N`. Then we can replace |*xy*| in the expression with `Math.nextAfter(N, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)`. This adds a slight amount (the slightest possible) to compensate for the fact that `N` might round down when converted to `double`. (We could also prepare `N` by converting it to a `double` with rounding toward ∞ instead of rounding to nearest.)

To deal with the second problem, we can convert 4•2<sup>−53</sup> + 3•2<sup>−106</sup> + 2<sup>−159</sup> to a `double` with rounding toward ∞. The result is 4•2<sup>−53</sup> + 3•2<sup>−106</sup>, or 2<sup>−51</sup> + 2<sup>−103</sup>. As of JDK 5, we can write that as `0x1.0000000000001p-51`.

The third problem can introduce a rounding error of at most 2<sup>−53</sup> relative to the result. However, in converting the error term to `double`, we rounded up by more than that (the amount by which 2<sup>−103</sup> exceeds 3•2<sup>−106</sup> + 2<sup>−159</sup> is less than 2<sup>−53</sup> times the error term), so, even if the computed result is rounded down by 2<sup>−53</sup> (relatively), it is still above the desired mathematical result.

Thus, `Assert.assertEquals("<exactResult>", <javaResult>, Math.nextAfter(N, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)*0x1.0000000000001p-51);` reports an error only if at least one of the following is true:

- `<javaResult>` is not the result of computing in `double` the product of two numbers converted from decimal numerals whose exact product is `<exactResult>`.
- `<exactResult>` is not in the normal range of `double`.
- The computed tolerance is not in the normal range of `double` (leading to it being rounded down by more than anticipated above). (Note that the second condition implies this third one, so the second one can be omitted.)

If `<exactResult>` is in the subnormal range, a small absolute value might be used for the tolerance, instead of a relative value. I omit discussion of that.

Note that this bound is such that the assert will not report an error if the product is as expected. However, it is not guaranteed to report an error if the product is wrong. The tolerance is more than four times the bound on the error of a single operation (because there were four operations involved). Thus, the assert will accept several values other than the proper result of computing the product. In other words, false negatives are possible for results that are very close to, but different from, the proper result.

This is **an** upper bound on the error. It might be possible to tighten it further with some more analysis, and it is possible to tighten more in some circumstances, such as if it is known that *xy* is exactly representable or if particular values for *x* and *y* are known.

I expect the `nextAfter` could be replaced with an increase to the error factor, but I have not done the analysis to be able to assert that, say, a one ULP increase suffices.

Comment: Dear Eric thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I will read it carefully first. Then probably accept it (assuming that such a detailed level should contain the answer of my question).